# C# WPF - How to simply update UI from another class/thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface

*I couldn't find a **simple** solution to this problem. That's why I'm asking.*

I have a WPF **window** like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="640" Height="480">

    <Button Name="xaml_button" Content="A Text."/>
</Window>
```

And a MainWindow **class**:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;

namespace WPF_Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            xaml_button.Content = "Text changed on start.";
        }
    }

    private void xaml_button_Click()
    {
        Threading.t1.Start();
        UIControl.ChangeButtonName("Updated from another CLASS.");
    }
}
```

The button's `Content` property **successfully** changed itself. But what I want to do, is to change the property in **another** class *or* thread. What I tried is this:

```
class UIControl
{
    public static void ChangeButtonName(string text)
    {
        var window = new MainWindow();
        window.xaml_button.Content = text;
    }
}
```

It obviously **doesn't work**, because the `public MainWindow()` changes the `Content` property back to the original one, and brings some issues along with it.

Also I want to use this while **multithreading**. My simple threading class looks like this:

```
class Threading
{
    public static Thread t1 = new Thread(t1_data);

    static void t1_data()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        UIControl.ChangeButtonName("Updated from another THREAD.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally you need to dispatch ui changes from another thread to the main Thread. Like there described: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14890338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I'd recommend declaring a **static** variable that holds a UI control of your likings, in this case, a `Button`. Also add `using System.Windows.Controls;` at the beginning. So your code should look like this:

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WPF_Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static Button xamlStaticButton;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            xamlStaticButton = xaml_button;
            xamlStaticButton.Content = "Text changed on start";
        }

        private void xaml_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Threading.t1.Start();
            UIControl.ChangeButtonName("Updated from another CLASS.");
        }
    }
}
```

So pretty much what I did was to make a **placeholder** for the button, then **assigning** it on start.

```
class UIControl : MainWindow
{
    public static void ChangeButtonName(string text)
    {
        App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate {
            xamlStaticButton.Content = text;
        });
    }
}
```

Now I **inherited** the `MainWindow` class to the `UIControl` class for the sake of convenience. Also to make this work with multithreading, I added the `App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate { /*your UI code you want to execute*/});`. This will **make sure** your UI will update even if you are on **another thread**.

Comment: *Much better*: use MVVM and bind the Button Content to a view model property.

Comment: I'll support @Clemens. Check out the MVVM Light Toolkit: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/